# Python - Make exception handling for raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I'm trying to get text from a tag in chromedriver with selenium in python. My code run correctly but when there's no tag that should I get, the script raise an error and stop. The error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class="section-facts-description-text"]"}
    (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174(e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

I want to make exception, so when selenium can't find the tag, it will print a message and not stop the script. My code:

```
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

def findLocation(location):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    print "please wait, I'll show you where "+location+" is"
    browser.get("https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/"+location+"/")
    try:
        elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="section-facts-description-text"]') 
        desc = elem.text
        print str(desc)
    except:    
        print "There's no description about this location"
```

I don't know what exception I should use to handle just that error. If I use just `except` it will print "There's no description about this location" too even there's that span tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your import section:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

And the try/except part is as follows:

```
try:
    # do stuff

except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

for except use

`except Exception:
       print "There's no description about this location"`